# Items obtained using retrofit2 when selected, is not shown in the spinner

Tags: android, spinner, retrofit2

Items are not displayed on the spinner initially too.When one clicks on the spinner we can see that it is populated and the data obtained from the web api(json array) using retrofit2 is shown.The selected item is neither shown on the spinner nor gets set to the edittext.

Code:

```
public class BranchsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button br_add;
String brName,brShortName;
EditText et_BrName,et_BrShName;
Spinner spinner_Branch;
List<BranchResponse> branch;
Integer brId;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_branchs);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    br_add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_bradd);
    et_BrName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextBrName);
    et_BrShName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextBrShName);
    spinner_Branch = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_br);
    final ArrayList<String> brList = new ArrayList<>();


            Callback <List<BranchResponse>> callback = new Callback<List<BranchResponse>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response<List<BranchResponse>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                    if (response.isSuccess()) {
                         branch = response.body();
                        brList.clear();
                        for(int i=0;i<branch.size();i++){
                            brName= branch.get(i).getBrName();
                            brShortName = branch.get(i).getBrShortName();
                            brId = branch.get(i).getBranchId();
                            brList.add(brName);

                        }
                        brList.add(0,"Select a Branch");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }else
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.raw().message().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "failure!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            };
            ApiManager.getApi().getService().getBranch().enqueue(callback);


    spinner_Branch.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(BranchsActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, brList));
    spinner_Branch.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?>parent,View view,int position,long id){
 //This toast is also not shown when the item is selected
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "item selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        et_BrName.setText(branch.get(position).getBrName());
        et_BrShName.setText(branch.get(position).getBrShortName());
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                "On Item Select : \n" + parent.getItemAtPosition(position-1).toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?>arg0){


        }
    });

}
```

I have gone through almost all of the posts dealing with spinner issues and tried all of the suggested answers but none of them solved this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(BranchsActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, brList);
spinner_Branch.setAdapter(mAdapter);

Callback <List<BranchResponse>> callback = new Callback<List<BranchResponse>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<List<BranchResponse>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                if (response.isSuccess()) {
                     branch = response.body();
                    brList.clear();
                    for(int i=0;i<branch.size();i++){
                        brName= branch.get(i).getBrName();
                        brShortName = branch.get(i).getBrShortName();
                        brId = branch.get(i).getBranchId();
                        brList.add(brName);

                    }

                    brList.add(0,"Select a Branch");
                    mAdapter.notifydatasetchanged();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }else
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.raw().message().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "failure!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        };
        ApiManager.getApi().getService().getBranch().enqueue(callback);
```

Comment: Thanks a tonne mahn! It's working! :) I should have initialized the adapter before! Thanks again!